# Connect to DAX cluster using dynamoose (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax, dynamoose

I am trying to connect to dax cluster from my node application

```
// Set document client to use dax cluster
var daxClient = null;

dynamoose.AWS.config.update({
    region: 'us-east-1'
});

var dax = new AmazonDaxClient({
    endpoints: [nconf.get('daxendpoint')],
    region: 'us-east-1'
});

daxClient = new dynamoose.AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ service: dax });
dynamoose.setDocumentClient(daxClient);
```

However, as per DAX Cluster metrics, looks like the connection is temporary:

[image]

The application is still directly reading from the dynamoDB table and not via DAX. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? We have the exact same issue at the moment

Comment: Have you solved it by now Shuchit Gandhi?  We have the same problem

Comment: is this working code? can you share dynamoose documentation link here?